# Can anyone tell me what this icon is?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s

I cannot figure this out, and it is really bugging me. Does anyone here know what this notification means?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you pull down notification bar to see which app is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a notification icon from [Boom Beach](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.boombeach) game from SuperCell

You can pull down the notification bar to see what the game is saying to you.